# Facing undefined error in json using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I am using javascript ajax to fetch data from the JSON API server and want to show these data in an HTML table.
But I get an undefined error in HTML data. That is

```
Name         id
undefined undefined
```

There is my code

```
<html>

<body>


      <table class = "src">
         <tr><th>Name</th><th>id</th></tr>
         <tr><td><div id="Name"></div></td>
         <td><div id="Id"></div></td></tr>
      </table>



   </body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {

               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)  {
                  // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
                  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                  // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
                  // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
                  document.getElementById("Name").innerHTML = jsonObj.name;
                  document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML = jsonObj.id;
               }
            }

             xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

What should I do to resove this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the data that you receive from ```jsonObj``` by doing ```console.log(jsonObj)``` ??

Comment: We can't help you without seeing the JSON, but apparently it isn't in the form `{"name": "some name", "id": "some id"}`. More: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json

Comment: Side note: You'd probably be better off assigning to `textContent` rather than `innerHTML`, in case either field has characters you don't want interpreted in their HTML sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to access an object, but the output of the API is actually an array. You can get the first object by doing `jsonObj[0]`, as follows:

```html
<html>

<body>


      <table class = "src">
         <tr><th>Name</th><th>id</th></tr>
         <tr><td><div id = "Name"></div></td>
         <td><div id = "Id"></div></td></tr>
      </table>



   </body>

</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(e) {

               if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)  {
                  // Javascript function JSON.parse to parse JSON data
                  var jsonObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

                  // jsonObj variable now contains the data structure and can
                  // be accessed as jsonObj.name and jsonObj.country.
                  document.getElementById("Name").textContent = jsonObj[0].name;
                  document.getElementById("Id").textContent = jsonObj[0].id;
               }
            }

             xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
</script>
```

See this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-kalam-xsru7?file=/index.html) where the code is working.

**Edit:** As [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) has mentioned, it is better to use `textContent` rather than `innerHTML` to avoid unwanted HTML to be rendered (never trust user input!).

Comment: @AwaisHassan in that case you need to loop over all items in the array, create new `tr` and `td` elements, set the contents there, and then insert the new elements into the `table`. have a look at [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and [`Element.insertAdjacentElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML).

Comment: how this will happen?

Comment: @AwaisHassan I recommend that you read up on how to loop through arrays and create new DOM elements in JavaScript, I have linked two pages that you can use for reference regarding creating DOM elements. To loop through the array you can use [`Array.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).